# AWS Pinpoint/SNS have people text to subscribe to topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, endpoint, subscribe, aws-pinpoint

Is there a way to have the customer/endpoint subscribe to a topic by texting the long code/short code number? Can they text a particular keyword to be subscribed to a particular topic? It seems like most the documentation and examples I am coming across has the owner subscribe customers/endpoints from their side.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the 2-Way SMS feature of Amazon Pinpoint. Here's a bit more on it to see if that is indeed what you were looking for: https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/what-is-two-way-sms/ and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-two-way.html